# How to mock a click event on an element in React using jest , react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My component renders the following

```
{list.options && list.options.length > 0 ? (
<div
    data-testId="MyAlertText" onClick={onAddText}>
    Add Text
</div>
) : null}
```

And, in my tests I am doing the following

```
it('Add Text link should render', () => {
    const { container, getByTestId} = render(<MyComp />);

    const link = getByTestId('MyAlertText');
    expect(link).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

It runs successfully

But when I try to run, and simulate `onClick` it fails.

[image]

```
it('Add Text link should call method', () => {
    const { container, getByTestId} = render(<MyComp />);

    const link = getByTestId('MyAlertText');
    expect(link).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.click(link );
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

I tried mocking the function using `jest mock`. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Does casing matter for attributes like this? I've always used `data-testid` instead of `data-testId`

Answer (score 1):

link.simulate('click') - should to the job!

Comment: can you provide more specific, since your answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry I am new to answering on stackoverflow. My post shortly answers what the problem of the poster is? AM I supposed to provide more information that the poster need? That is how you simulate clicks with jest, I don't know what else I can add to make it more specific maybe you can enlighten me :D

Comment: This will work if you are using enzyme but not if you are using testing-library, like OP asked

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't worry about testing methods *inside* your component. Rather, you should test the **side effects** of those methods.

Of course `onAddText` will be called (or whatever `onAddText` references), but what does `onAddText` actually do? Test that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shallow` in [jest](https://jestjs.io/) to resolve your case.

```
it('Add Text link should render', async () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComp />);
  const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onAddText');
  wrapper.find('#MyAlertText').simulate('click');
  await wrapper.update();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```